# Помогите разобраться с angular-translate и ui.router

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Добрый день. Не поможете разобраться с проблемой и подсказать решение? 
Стоит задача, при загрузке сайта пользователем, определять язык и выдавать сразу на языке пользователя контент.
 Т.е. при языке пользователя русский - выдавать сразу www.site.com/ru и любые ссылки делать вида www.site.com/ru/o-site.
 В случае англоязычного, выдавать www.site.com/en и www.site.com/en/about, соответственно.Если язык по какой то причине не определяется, то используется fallback ('en')

Использую angular-translate и ui.router.

При заходе на сайт в конфиге я делаю так

```
        $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');
        $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escaped');
        $translateProvider.determinePreferredLanguage(); (Ну и простыня из всех  'en_AU.utf8': 'en', и так далее)
```

Всё нормально, язык мы получили. Далее, полазив по сети ( [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281652/localize-urls-with-ui-router-and-angular-translate) или  [ссылка](http://fadeit.dk/blog/post/angular-translate-ui-router-seo) ) , предлагается использовать ui-router с "верхним" уровнем, типа

```
angular.module('app').config([
   '$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('app', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/{locale}'
});
$stateProvider.state('app.root', {
  url: ''
});
return $stateProvider.state('app.root.about', {
  url: '/about'
});
 }
]);
```

Но вот дальше за гранью моего понимания. Что необходимо сделать дальше? У меня есть язык, полученный с помощью angular-translate, например, так

```
  function MainController($translate) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.locale = $translate.use() ||         $translate.storage().get($translate.storageKey()) || $translate.preferredLanguage();
}
```

Как мне привязать его к роутеру? И заодно "исправить" ссылки -

```
ui-sref="about" на ui-sref="o_site"?
```

Я хочу привязать к роутеру сервис, который будет дергать из базы контент, с определенным locale, там же будут и прописаны slug (alias)

Comment: Т.е., наверное, первоначально, я понимаю. Я определяю язык - обращаюсь к сервису, которые берет из базы "всё, что есть с параметром locale", оттуда подставляются slug, но как это "засунуть" в роутер, чтобы сразу вышло www.site.com/en ?

Comment: в ui-sref можно вызывать state с параметром